# Xml parsing on spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, xml-parsing, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to analyze data using Kinesis source in PySpark Structured Streaming on Databricks.

I created a Dataframe as shown below.

```
kinDF = spark.readStream.format("kinesis").("streamName", "test-stream-1").load()
```

Later I converted the data from base64 encoding as below.

```
df =  kinDF.withColumn("xml_data", expr("CAST(data as string)"))
```

Now, I need to extract few fields from df.xml_data column using xpath. Can you please suggest any possible solution?

If I create a dataframe directly for these xml files as `xml_df = spark.read.format("xml").options(rowTag='Consumers').load("s3a://bkt/xmldata")`, I'm able to query using xpath:

```
xml_df.select("Analytics.Amount1").show()
```

But, not sure how to do extract elements similarly on a Spark Streaming dataframe where data is in text format.

Are there any xml functions to convert text data using schema? I saw an example for json data using from_json.

Is it possible to use spark.read on a dataframe column?

I need to find aggregated "Amount1" for every 5 minutes window.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlReader` to read xml data from column but requires an RDD, which means that you need to transform your `df` to `RDD` using `df.rdd` which may impact performance.

Below is untested code from spark java:

```
import com.databricks.spark.xml

xmlRdd = df = kinDF.select("xml_data").map(r -> r[0])
new XmlReader().xmlRdd(spark, xmlRdd)
```

Comment: Is this available in Pyspark? Also, Is this supported in Streaming Application?